# ARC warning: Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting, c99

I use `DLog` macro in an **ARC** project, and I got the warning:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99
```

You can find `DLog` from http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog

How to fix this warning?

Answer (score 2):

I actually had this warning when calling Dlog without a capital L. I changed it into DLog and everything worked fine. But you seem to have it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Prefix.pch file is included in 'Build Settings' -> 'Prefix Header'