# Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, nslog, release-mode

I used a macro version of NSLog from here, http://objdev.com/2014/06/debug-logging

like this,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s(%p) %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif
```

It was working fine, until I changed the app run mode from `Debug` to `Release`.

Now I get the following error:

> Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99.

How do I solve this?

I read many questions,
[error:'implicit declaration of function 'nslog' is invalid at C99'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264421/errorimplicit-declaration-of-function-nslog-is-invalid-at-c99), [ARC warning: Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799838/arc-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-dlog-is-invalid-in-c99) and [Implicit declaration of function - C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704335/implicit-declaration-of-function-c99),
but none of the answers work for me.

P.S. This question isn't related to **CocoaLumberjack** at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Error tells you that `DLog` doesn't have any definition in `Release` Mode.
Just change it to this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s(%p) %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#else
#define DLog(...)
#endif
```

EDIT : If it is a Release mode DLog will do nothing(A Blank Function). And if it is a debug mode DLog will print the log as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I just did it like this way only and it worked, one question is it proper?

Comment: Yes. It is perfectly alright.
If it is a Release mode DLog will do nothing(A Blank Function).
And if it is a debug mode DLog will print the log as per your requirements.

Comment: `DLog(@"Thanks Nirav!");` ;)

Comment: DLog(@"WelCome Michael!");

Answer (score 0):

The macro is only defined when you compile your code e debug mode because of the `#ifdef DEBUG` directive